What do these terms mean in general?坐支in particular
第二十六条　各部门及其所属单位应当及时收取各类资产收入，不得违反国家规定，多收、少收、不收、侵占、私分、截留、占用、挪用、隐匿、坐支。
Excerpt from 行政事业性国有资产管理条例（国务院令第738号）
What do the financial terms mean, especially the 坐支?

You can google for the meanings, here is one for "坐支" - https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%9D%90%E6%94%AF/5026614#:~:text=%E5%9D%90%E6%94%AF%E5%B0%B1%E6%98%AF%E6%8A%8A%E6%94%B6%E5%88%B0,%E5%8A%A1%E5%A4%84%E7%90%86%EF%BC%8C%E5%8D%B3%E4%B8%BA%E5%9D%90%E6%94%AF%E3%80%82

@r13 Thank you for the guidance, but could you briefly explain it in English for me because i do not really understand it

The simple explanation from Google Translate, "坐支" is that an accountant pays out the money received from payee A to recipient B without doing any accounting/booking.

坐支：sitting payments
I would understand that as:
Use cash income to pay outgoings.
用现金收入支付支出。
坐支是指有现金收入的单位，
坐支 refers to work units with a cash income,
从本单位收入的现金中直接支付现金的做法。
using that money to directly pay cash expenses.
在一般情况下，
Under normal circumstances,
不允许坐支现金。
this is not allowed.
但为了使某些单位避免向银行存取现金时相向运送，
However, in order to help some work units avoid having to transport cash to or from the bank,
我国现金管理办法规定下列单位的有些用途可以允许坐支：
China's cash management guidelines allow certain work units to use the practice of 坐支:
(1) 基层供销社、粮店、食品站、委托商店等兼营收购和销售的单位，

Basic supply companies, grain stores, foodstuff stores，department stores etc. which simultaneously buy and sell,
以销售收入支付采购款；
may use their income directly for procurement.

(2) 邮局以汇兑收入支付汇款，
Post Offices may use deposit income to pay withdrawals.
医院以收入款退还病人预收款；
hospitals may use income to refund monies paid by patients;
(3) 其他有特殊情况的单位。
Other work units with special circumstances.
为加强银行对坐支单位的严格控制，
In order to strengthen strict bank control over work units which engage in the practice of 坐支,
需要坐支的单位应事先提出申请，
work units which need 坐支 must apply for permission in advance,
经开户银行审查同意，
(and) agree to inspection by the bank,
在核定的坐支限额内坐支。
the amount of 坐支 must be within the limits set (by the bank.)

Are you sure that "sitting payment" is an accepted term? I haven't found it online so far. What is the "sitting" different than the one in "sitting president"?

No, not sure, that's just what it says. Maybe you are familiar with the phrase "sitting on a whole pile of cash", which means "in possession of a lot of money". To my mind it's fairly intuitive: use the cash you are sitting on, instead of carting that to the bank and then getting cash from the bank to pay cash to other sellers.. All probably redundant now in this age of electronic payments! WeChat, WhatsApp, AliPay, no problem!
